# Double-sided queue problem

Tags: java, deque

I am trying to run this method to insert a generic value (EltType) into an double sided queue(deque), but I keep getting an outOfBoundsException that I just can't figure out. Would anyone please be able to help me with this ? This is just an extract from the code, but I think it can be pieced together from this!

```
  private final int CAPACITY = 10;
  private int capacity;
  private int end;
  private EltType deque[];  

  public ArrayBasedDeque() {
    this.capacity = CAPACITY;
    deque = (EltType[]) (new Object[capacity]);  
  }

    public void insertFirst(EltType first) {
        if(!isEmpty()) {
        EltType[] tempArray;
        tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[CAPACITY+1];
        for (int i=0;i<=deque.length;i++) {
          tempArray[i+1] = deque[i]; 
        }
        deque = tempArray; 
        }
       deque[0] = first;
      }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    boolean returned;
    if (deque.length < 1) {
     returned = true; 
    }else {
     returned = false; 
    }
    return returned;
  }
```

Error :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at ArrayBasedDeque.insertFirst(ArrayBasedDeque.java:48)
    at TestABD.main(TestABD.java:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:271)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<=deque.length;i++) {
```

should be changed into

```
for (int i=0;i<deque.length;i++) {
```

You used a "smaller than or equal", but the last item of an array has (length-1) for index.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers about `<=`, you're setting the temp array size to CAPACITY+1, which will always be 11. You probably meant:

```
tempArray = (EltType[]) new Object[capacity+1];
```

Comment: Also, I would not recommend having variable names that only differ by their case. It's bad practice and you can see here why. I would rename your constant to INITIAL_CAPACITY.

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have mentioned, you have an "off-by-one" error, also called a fencepost error.

Also, you can simplify your `isEmpty()` method as follows:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return end == 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that when `end` is zero, then that means there are no elements in the deque.  You shouldn't check `deque.length`, because that simply tells you how many elements the array can store, not how many are currently in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you changing your capacity?  It probably shouldn't be a constant.  The size is also not being incremented when you add.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i=0;i<=deque.length;i++) {
```

You should use `<`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

B/c you are using <=, you go up to deque.length which is 10, but deque only has 9 indices.

```
 for (int i=0;i<=deque.length;i++) {
          tempArray[i+1] = deque[i]; 
 }
```

Use < instead in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

As a side note:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
  boolean returned;
  if (deque.length < 1) {
   returned = true; 
  }else {
   returned = false; 
  }
  return returned;
}
```

Doesn't:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
  deque.length < 1
}
```

look simplier?

Comment: You missed the `return` keyword ;)