# Manually manipulating ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an assignment where I have to create a deque, however I am not allowed to use any built-in classes or interfaces. I am implementing my deque using an array list. My problem is that when I have to, for instance, add to the beginning of the array list (beginning of the queue), i am not allowed to do this:

```
public void addFirst(ArrayList<Integer> array) 
{
    array.add(0, int);
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using the add() function? Such as manually adding to the front and shifting the rest of the array to the right? Or maybe creating a new array list and copying...I'm not sure. Any help would be great; I have a bunch of functions to write, and getting the first one done will definitely put me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Well ArrayList is also a built-in class.

Comment: Also, you can add elements in the front of your arraylist. Why are you inserting `int`?? That is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Do you remember the lecture your teacher gave on linked lists? Or possibly...a fixed size circular array buffer/queue? Both of those data structures provide efficient ways to add and remove from both the front and end of a list.

Comment: also, I suspect you mean a queue, not a "deque"?

Comment: 'int' refers to any integer I want to insert. I am supposed to use array lists...

Comment: And just to clarify, I'm implementing a double-ended queue. The book/professor refers to it as a D.Q. or deque.

Comment: Pls refer to the discussion at this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927408/problems-with-implementing-a-deque-in-java

Comment: @jsan, personally, I would recommend you not call it that.  For an overwhelming majority of programmers and CS folks, "deque" is a verb whereby an element is removed. I would call it a doubly-linked list.

Comment: @kurtzbot, deque (when pronounced "deck") is a double ended queue. deque (when pronounced as de-que) is the verb you are referring too. So deque is a legitimate term for a double ended queue (albeit confusing when in writing).

Answer (score 2):

If you're not allowed to use any of the built in list classes, I suspect you should be looking at arrays, not ArrayList. There are functions like [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) that may help you here.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrayList< T >
{
   private int _capacity;
   private int _size;
   private T   _data;

   ArrayList( int capacity )
   {
      _capacity = capacity;
      _size     = 0;
      _data     = new T[_capacity];
   }

   void add( T t )
   {
      if( _size < _capacity )
      {
         _data[_size++] = t;
      }
      else
      {
         // do it yourself
      }
   }

   void insert( int index, T t )
   {
      if( _size < _capacity )
      {
         System.arrayCopy( _data, index, _data, index + 1, _size - index );
         _data[_size++] = t;
      }
      else
      {
         // do it yourself
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: This is a homework problem, and we shouldn't be posting full solutions to homework here. We should be helping guide in the right direction but not doing the OPs homework.

Comment: This is because I add some "..." and "do it yourself" ;-)